# What data type to use if user is asked to input integers and letters?

Tags: java, input, primitive-types

I am new in programming. My instructor gave me a special project about number base.

Since the higher number base are a combination of integers and letters, I'm still confused if I should use `int` and/or `char`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the base you want to convert and base to be converted: ");
        int firstBase = in.nextInt();
        int secondBase = in.nextInt();

        switch(firstBase) {
            case 2:
                System.out.print("Enter value: ");
                // I get confused here already
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
            case 16:
            case 20:
            case 24:
            case 26:
            case 27:
            case 30:
            case 32:
            case 36:    
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at `String`. Although you might want to be a bit more specific and give examples of what your data looks like.

Comment: Is using String an option? Or does it have to me a primitive type?

Comment: You should probably describe what you're trying to do, because you might use both and/or neither. A `String` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: That code looks a bit weird. Your `switch` statement prints some text if `firstBase` has the value `2`, then it uses a **fall-through** and *activates* all other cases. However the other cases don't do anything. You could just drop all cases and use the `break` statement in your first case to prevent a **fall-through**. After all, what are you exactly trying to achieve with that `switch` stuff?

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly enumerate the bases that you want to convert: provided it's at least 2 and at most 36, you should just handle the conversion in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick overview of some types:

- `char` - only a single letter or character
- `int` - numbers only without decimals
- `double` - numbers with decimals
- `String` - both numbers and letters

So based on your requirement you have to select `String`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store numbers and letters, than you can use `char`, since technically letters *and* numbers are characters. Alternatively you can use `String`, which can store anything from a single character, to complete paragraphs.